# How to change the value of node

Tags: c#, xml

The XML File Data is give below I want to Change the value of Price node of Urdu Book in c# . How to Do it!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Product>
        <Name>English Book</Name>
        <Pieces>10</Pieces>
        <RemainingPieces>5</RemainingPieces>
        <Price>100</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Urdu Book</Name>
        <Pieces>20</Pieces>
        <RemainingPieces>10</RemainingPieces>
        <Price>1000</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Grammar Book</Name>
        <Pieces>20</Pieces>
        <RemainingPieces>10</RemainingPieces>
        <Price>1000</Price>
    </Product>
</Data>
```

Comment: do a simple google search `C# stackoverflow how to change a node value in xml file` tons of working examples out there on the internet

Comment: Working with XML in C# has been covered repeatedly and extensively in numerous places. A cursory Google search like @MethodMan recommended is a good place to start. Please try something first and come back when you have a much more specific question about *code you've written*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Linq to XML as this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("book.xml"); 
doc.Element("Data")
    .Element("Product")
    .Element("Price")
    .SetElementValue("value"); 
doc.Save("book_modified.xml");
```

[About Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Haven't tried compiling but should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this to deal with your xml?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
byte[] strAsBytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(strYourXml);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(strAsBytes);

ds.ReadXml(ms);

string serach_name = "Urdu Book";
string new_value = 42;

if ((ds.Tables("Product") != null)) {

    foreach (DataRow t_row in ds.Tables("Product").Rows) {
        if ((t_row("Name") == serach_name)) {
            t_row("Price") = new_value;
            break; 
        }

    }
}
```